# Get all related sister (same content type) nodes through a view in Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

On my node detail page, I am hoping to show all the related nodes through a view which have the same taxonomy term(s) selected.

How can I make sure to get the related nodes on the node detail page (Note:- I don't have taxonomy term in the URL )

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter nodes with the same taxonomy term, when a node is displayed as main content (/node/???)

View , Display as block

2 contextual filters:

- Content: nid -> provide default value: content id from url - more: exclude
- Content: Has taxonomy term ID -> provide default value: taxonomy term id from url

It is important to put the contextual filters in this order, the first filter excludes the actual node from display, the exclude-checkbox is at the end under "More"

add additional filters, for example:

- Content: your content-type
- Content: Published (Yes)

Put the view block right below your Main page content in the Content-Region